# Haskell list difference operator in F#

Tags: haskell, f#, functional-programming, operators

Is there an equivalent operator to Haskell's list difference operator `\\` in F#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was bounced, yet I believe it is worth to write here the implementation of `( /-/ )` (the F# version of Haskell's `\\`):

```
let flip f x y = f y x

let rec delete x = function
  | [] -> []
  | h :: t when x = h -> t
  | h :: t -> h :: delete x t

let inline ( /-/ ) xs ys = List.fold (flip delete) xs ys
```

This will operate as Haskell's `\\`, so that `(xs @ ys) /-/ xs = ys`. For example: `(7 :: [1 .. 5] @ [5 .. 11]) /-/ [4 .. 7]` evaluates into `[1; 2; 3; 5; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11]`.

Answer (score 5):

Nope... Just write it and make it an infix operator --using the set of special characters. Backslash (`\`) is not in the list below, so it will not work as an infix operator. See the [manual](http://research.microsoft.com/fsharp/manual/spec2.aspx#_Toc207785578):

> infix-op :=
>
> ```
> or || & && <OP >OP $OP = |OP &OP ^OP :: -OP +OP *OP /OP %OP
>
> **OP
> ```
>
> prefix-op :=
>
> ```
> !OP ?OP ~OP -OP +OP % %% & &&
> ```

Comment: "// will work as an infix operator". No it won't. That is a single-line comment in F#.

Answer (score 2):

Filter items from the set of the subtrahend:

```
let ( /-/ ) xs ys =
    let ySet = set ys
    let notInYSet x = not <| Set.contains x ySet
    List.filter notInYSet xs
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this:

```
let (/-/) l1 l2 = List.filter (fun i -> not <| List.exists ((=) i) l2) l1
```

If anyone sees a problem, let me know.

Is for lists, so there could be duplicates in the result. For example:

```
[1;1;2] /-/ [2;3] would be eq to [1;1]
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you really want conventional set difference rather than the weird ordered-but-unsorted multiset subtraction that Haskell apparently provides, just convert the lists to sets using the built-in `set` function and then use the built-in `-` operator to compute the set difference:

```
set xs - set ys
```

For example:

```
> set [1..5] - set [2..4];;
val it : Set<int> = seq [1; 5]
```

Comment: The edit still doesn't handle duplicates correctly. The \\ operator doesn't provide a set-difference behaviour, it provides a bag-difference behaviour.

Comment: @Scott: Thanks. Looks like it probably isn't worth doing a faithful translation. I doubt anyone would ever want that functionality...

Comment: @Jon I imagine it would depend on whether your underlying model is bags or sets.

Comment: Haskell's function isn't really for bags either because it specifies order (the first occurrence must be removed).

Comment: The function is for lists, so there is an order. The fact that it's more specified makes it a refinement of the bag operation.

Comment: Then I don't see the relevance of bags because every such operation is a refinement of a bag operation. This is some kind of ordered-but-unsorted multiset.

Comment: Bags are relevant because the bag-difference operator better describes the difference operator you tried to give an implementation for, opposed to the set-difference operator.

Comment: But all of the operators described so far including the one I tried to give an implementation for were ordered whereas "bag" means unordered?

Comment: Ah, I said that this was a refinement of a bag operation. Ie, if you implemented a bag as a list you could use the // operator for lists, and it would be an implementation of the bag-difference operator. Likewise, ++ would be an implementation of the bag-sum operator. The fact that there is an order is just more information, which doesn't influence the bag interface (because it doesn't know about it anyway).